# implementing tableview subview popup controller to google maps view swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift, but I'm trying to implement a table view from one view controller to another by clicking an element from the child view controller then navigating to the appropriate GMSCameraPosition. The function call works, however the camera won't update for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
 import UIKit
 import GoogleMaps

 class PopUpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var buildingsList: UITableView!

let buildings = ["MESA Building",
                 "Science and Technology Building",
                 "Library Building",
                 "Student Activity Center Building (SAC)",
                 "Founders Building",
                 "Gym Complex",
                 "CEED Building",
                 "Arts Building"]


//var camera = GMSCameraPosition()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.showAnimate()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.removeAnimate()
    //self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    //Do thing here
}



//
//TableView Functions
//


//Manages the sections of TabelView
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//Adds rows to tableView
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return(buildings.count)

}

//Adds text to each cell/row
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = buildings[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)
}
//Action performed when cell is clicked
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let row = buildings[indexPath.row]
    print(row)
    if (row == "MESA Building")
    {

    MapViewController().setLocation()
    self.removeAnimate()
    }

}




//
//Popup Functions
//
func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.25, y: 0.25)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    });
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.25, y: 0.25)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
        if (finished)
        {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
  }
}
```

MapViewController

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var googleMaps: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var buildingsTable: UITableView!

var locManager: CLLocationManager!

static var camera = GMSCameraPosition()
static var mapView = GMSMapView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.delegate = self


    //default location for google maps
    MapViewController.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 31.888401, longitude: -102.323992, zoom: 15.5)

    //mapView allows user to interact with the UI
    MapViewController.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: MapViewController.camera)
    self.view.addSubview(MapViewController.mapView)
    //self.view = mapView

    //Creates the nav button on the UI to show the buildings
    let buildingsButton = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "nav")
    buildingsButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 65, y: 70, width: 57, height: 57)
    //button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
    buildingsButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    buildingsButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    buildingsButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    buildingsButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    buildingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buildingsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buildingsButton)


    //adds the compass button at the top of the UI
    MapViewController.mapView.settings.compassButton = true

    //shows visibility to the elements in the Google Maps UI
    MapViewController.mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

    //checks if user allows their location to be used, then will find location on the map
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        print("All set!")
        //finds the location of the user
        MapViewController.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        //allows the user to click on a button to recented their current location
        MapViewController.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        //constantly updates the users location in the UI
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else{
        print("Asking user for their location!")

        //Asks the user if they would like to share their location
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            //finds the location of the user
            MapViewController.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

            //allows the user to click on a button to recented their current location
            MapViewController.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            //constantly updates the users location in the UI
            locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    //Array of buildings to be user as markers
    let buildings = [
        Building(name: "Library", lat: 31.888199, long: -102.328775),
        Building(name: "MESA Building", lat: 31.889575, long:-102.329833),
        Building(name: "Science and Technology (ST) Building", lat: 31.888787, long:-102.327587),
        Building(name: "Student Activity Canter (SAC) Building", lat: 31.889445, long:-102.328128),
        Building(name: "Founders Building", lat: 31.885989, long:-102.3222291),
        Building(name: "Gym Complex", lat: 31.890361, long:-102.328636),
        Building(name: "CEED Building", lat: 31.970513, long:-102.249466),
        Building(name: "Arts Building", lat: 31.891409, long:-102.327194),
        Building(name: "(New)Residence and Dining Hall", lat: 31.888886, long:-102.325978),

        ]


    //for loop using the array and structure to place the markers accordingly
    for building in buildings {
        let building_marker = GMSMarker()
        building_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: building.lat, longitude: building.long)
        building_marker.title = building.name
        //  building_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is \(building.name)"
        building_marker.map = MapViewController.mapView
        building_marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    }

}


//structure that initializes the variables for the markers
struct Building {
    let name: String
    let lat: CLLocationDegrees
    let long: CLLocationDegrees
}

func buildingsButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")

    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    }

func setLocation(){


    MapViewController.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 31.888199, longitude: -102.328775, zoom: 15.5)
    MapViewController.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: MapViewController.camera)
    self.view.addSubview(MapViewController.mapView)

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by what you are trying to do. Could you show the full classes with their properties? Are the `TableViewController` and the `MapViewController` on the same `ViewController`?  You may have to switch to using delegates for this, if they are.

Comment: I'm using two view controllers, the MapViewController and the PopUpViewController. the table view is located inside of the PopUpViewController, but they technically are both nested in the MapViewController and triggered by a button that sows the table over the MapsViewController. I'm still learning and I'm sure there is a way easier way to do this, that is why I'm reaching out.